# Shift rows by group by random generated delta t

Tags: r, random, dataframe, rows, shift

Here an example of my data.frame:

```
df = read.table(text = 'ID Day
101 0
101 0
101 1
300 40
300 40
270 32
270 35
100 1450
100 1450
100 1451
72 1490
72 1499', header = TRUE)
```

Assuming that each `Day` obs represents a real date and that the time period ranges from `Day` = 0 to `Day` = 1500, I need to shift each `ID` group by a random amount of `Day` (delta t), specific for each group and if the `Day` value passes 1500 start again from 0.

e.g. group 101 by 30 Day, group 300 by 70, group 270 by 1000, group 100 by 100 and group 72 by 5

Here my desired output:

```
     ID Day
    101 30
    101 30
    101 31
    300 110
    300 110
    270 1032
    270 1035
    100 1550
    100 1550
    100 1551
    72 1495
    72 3
```

Note that the shift in `Day` per each group has to be random.

Any help would be really appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Not sure if I got it, but with `data.table` you could try `setDT(df)[,Day_new:=(Day+runif(uniqueN(ID),0,1500))%%1500,by=ID]`.

Comment: sorry but it does not work, thanks anyway

Comment: I believe the trick is to add the random numbers to each Day within each group of IDs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
library(dplyr)

set.seed(123)

df2 <- df %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  mutate(Day = (Day + sample(1:1000, 1)) %% 1500)
```

Answer (score 2):

This will add a random integer between 0 and 1000 to each day - you could adjust the bounds of `sample` depending on what you need.

```
library(dplyr)

set.seed(123)

df2 <- df %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  mutate(Day = (Day + sample(1:1000, 1)) %% 1500)

df2      
# ID   Day
# 101   409
# 101   409
# 101   410
# 300   981
# 300   981
# 270   916
# 270   919
# 100   739
# 100   739
# 100   740
# 72   278
# 72   287
```

Comment: sorry but I got negative Day values...why?

Comment: can you show the before and after values that are giving the negative numbers? In `mutate` you could make the new variable a different name (say `Day2`) that might help you troubleshoot

Comment: if you remove the last row of your code Day = replace(Day, Day > 1500, Day - 1500) it works

Comment: I think `mutate(Day = (Day + sample(1:1000, 1))%%1500)` will work.

Comment: @user2100721 it works. if you post a complete answer I will mark it as correct. thank again to both.